# Table Design - Wide Table vs. Columns as Properties

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I'm part of a team architecting an Operational Data Store (ODS) database, using SQL Server 2012, that will be used by some of our analysts to do predictive modeling. The ODS will contain manufacturing production data for a single product we make.

We will have hundreds of tables in the ODS. However, we will have a single core table that will contain critical information (lifecycle info) about each item manufactured (tens of millions each year). Our product is manufactured in a manufacturing plant and spends roughly 2.5 hours moving through various processes along a production line. We want to store various, individual, pieces of manufacturing and post manufacturing information in this core table. An example piece of data might be the time the product entered a particular oven.

We have a decision to make on how to architect this table. We can create a wide table (many columns) or a narrow table where most columns are rows (as property values). I have never designed and worked with a table structure that is very narrow and columns are treated as rows in the table.

I'd like some feedback on the pros and cons of a wide table vs. a narrow table. The following might be useful in helping with this discussion:

Number of products produced each year:  Several million (each of these product instances will be a row in the core table)

Will this table be queried often: Yes, very often. It will be the parent to many child tables.

Potential number of columns (or row properties): 75 to 150+

If more information would be useful, I'd be glad to provide it.

Comment: What reasons have you or your colleagues given for the narrow table design?  For example, do you plan on frequently changing the set of properties being tracked?  Are you concerned about data storage (i.e. you want to minimize the unused columns per record)?

Comment: Yes, we could be adding properties (columns) somewhat often, as we begin tracking data we were not tracking before. Storage is not a huge concern. I think the biggest concern of a wide table is just dealing with the efficiency (lack of?) of dealing with a heavily usesd table where each row could be several thousand bytes in length.

Comment: I would look into [Data Warehousing](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/solutions-technologies/data-warehousing.aspx).  The table designs tend to be very different than transactional databases, with an emphasis on ease of reporting and tracking historical values that would normally be overwritten in a transactional design.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Wide tables, static properties**

You are tracking a single product through a well-defined manufacturing process. This data model sounds very static, and would lend itself to a wide table with many columns that are consistently populated with data.

**Narrow tables, dynamic properties**

If you had many, many products with lots of variation in the manufacturing process, it would be better suited for a narrow table, where you could easily add new properties for tracking.

**Difficult to query a narrow table**

However, even simple querying of a narrow table can extremely difficult. For example, what if you needed to sort the data by a certain property when that property is shuffled amongst 100+ other property rows? How would you get all the rows together to form a single "record" and then sort the record groups within your result set?

**Flat tables simpler to query**

Depending on how you need to view and analyze the data, you may find yourself constantly using pivot or crosstab queries. If that's the case, then why not flatten out the storage table to begin with?

**Or do both**

Another option is to do both: Store the data narrowly, and use a transformation process to flatten it out for ease of reporting. That way you can quickly begin tracking new properties (just by adding rows), and then you can work on getting your reporting tables and transformation process updated to utilize the new data.

Answer (score 0):

How wide is too wide?  Well, there can be several problems with wide tables.

One problem is that wide tables tend to deviate from the rules for normalizing data.  This in turn can result in tricky update problems where you have to be careful to prevent the database from entering a self contradictory state. There's no particular answer to how wide it too wide here.  Just apply the normalization rules, and you'll end up decomposing the table.

However, some databases are not built with normalization as the guiding principle.  In particular, consider fact tables in star schemas.  There are times when some of the coulmns are determined by some subset of the FK's, and this can violate 3NF or even 2NF.  Keeping fact tables skinny is still important in star schemas, but it's for a different reason, namely speed.  Sometimes, a fact table can be made skinnier by pushing data out to one of the dimension tables.  Sometimes, you can decompose a star into two or more related stars.

Your case sounds like the second reason given above, even though your design probably isn't a star schema.  Still, star schema design principles might help you improve your design.